# Android: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

Tags: android, react-native

Excuse me, I am not familiar with react-native and android. When I load my react-native project for the first time and try to sync and update I get this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `google()` for your build script repo. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839

i.e.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```