# Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I have updated my Android project from version 23 to 26. I received the error message below. Any idea?

```
Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1.
Required by:
    project :app

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager
```

[image]

Comment: You'll need to download support library from SDK manager for version 26, it's missing for you.

Comment: @JeelVankhede - Could you please advise where can I find the download button? I have my SDK manager screenshot attached above.

Comment: When you select your desired packages to download, click **"Ok"** button below, it'll ask you about confirmation to download packages.

Comment: Maybe same problem as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839

Answer (score 0):

In the android gradle file you need to specify the following:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

Then, find the text `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7"`
and make sure it says

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"
```

Comment: Can you please show me when to download the correspond library? I have added the mentioned library but still I couldn't refer to the compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1".