# SDK manager will not open on Mac

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I have installed java 8 and following the tutorial on how to download android sdk without android studio for Mac https://www.androidcentral.com/installing-android-sdk-windows-mac-and-linux-tutorial

When I try open the sdkmanager it says this on terminal

```
inconsistent location '/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/28.0.3' (Expected '/Users/username/build-tools/28.0.3'). 

 Warning: Observed package id 'emulator' in inconsistent location    '/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/emulator' (Expected '/Users/username/emulator')
  Warning: Observed package id 'extras;android;m2repository' in    inconsistent location   '/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository' (Expected '/Users/username/extras/android/m2repository')
 Warning: Observed package id 'extras;google;m2repository' in inconsistent location '/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository' (Expected '/Users/username/extras/google/m2repository')
  Warning: Observed package id 'extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager' in inconsistent location '/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_.Execution_Manager' (Expected '/Users/username/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager')
 Warning: Observed package id 'patcher;v4' in inconsistent location '/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/patcher/v4' (Expected '/Users/username/patcher/v4')

   logout
  Saving session...
  ...copying shared history...
  ...saving history...truncating history files...
  ...completed.
```

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839

Comment: how is your `local.properties` file like? make sure the `sdk.dir` points to the correct SDK location.

Comment: tools and platform-tools folders are missing. So how to I point it to correct sdk location

Comment: open your Android Studio, using SDK manager to download it or you can download a new android studio, there should be a step asking you to install missing SDKs

Comment: You issue looks like your Android SDK is not complete. so just try to download fresh Android Studio and let AS to do it for you

Comment: I do not want to download android studio as its 1gb. I just need the sdk for react native etc and not using android studio as an editor. Is there any way around not downloading android studio. Can I delete android studio after installs missing sdks.

Comment: or you can just download Android SDK Manager to download a complete set of SDK

Comment: Am I able to delete android studio and keep the sdkmanager as it lot memory I do not need.

Comment: sure, after you get your Android Studio download your needed SDK, then you can delete AS completely. But here is a way with SDK manager only: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.