# Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.4. Searched in the following locations

Tags: java, android, android-studio

please help I have this error in android studio

```
Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.4.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/samir/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.pom
    file:/C:/Users/samir/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.jar
    file:/C:/Users/samir/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.pom
    file:/C:/Users/samir/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.jar
    file:/C:/Users/samir/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.pom
    file:/C:/Users/samir/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.4/lint-gradle-26.1.4.jar
    file:/C:/Users/samir/Desktop/webviewapp-2.2.0/mobile/libs/lint-gradle-26.1.4.jar
    file:/C:/Users/samir/Desktop/webviewapp-2.2.0/mobile/libs/lint-gradle.jar
Required by:
    project :mobile here
```

Comment: Similar as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839, try this to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

1- close unity

2- go to "C:\Users(user name)"

3- delete ".gradle" folder

try bulid project now