# Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.0.1)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, builder, android-studio-3.2

I update my android studio to 3.2.1
now when I start a new project everything is OK.
but when I open the last project I have an error :

> Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.0.1).
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.0.1/builder-3.0.1.jar

```
build.gradle: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

My gradle version 4.1

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839

Comment: getting same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all try to invalide caches and restart AS (Android Studio). (File --> Invalide Caches/Restart). If that won't work try to sync project with Gradle Files 
(File --> Sync project with Gradle files). If it won't work head on to build.gradle(Project: yourappname) and change gradle line in dependencies to the newest version:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
       }
```

hope it will work for you, if not I'll search for other solution

Comment: how to find the latest version, i have 3.3.1 in android studio 3.3.1

Comment: Thanks mate. Doing invalid Caches/Restart worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio: 3.3.0 - 3.3.1 requires Gradle version: 4.10.1+
in Android Gradle plugin release notes you can see the Required Gradle version for Android Studio version.

- update your gradle plugin to 5.2.1 (current version)
  see this Question similar Answer :
  [How to update gradle in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727645/how-to-update-gradle-in-android-studio)

references:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle
current version of gradle: 5.2.1: https://gradle.org/releases/