# 'Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve' in android studios bumblebee 2021 patch

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to implement other library in my project. When I am implementing any library getting like '`Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.0.1.`. I have checked many solution but did'nt worked. I am using gradle version

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
    }
```

I am using sdk version 31.I have tried many solution but did'nt worked.

- [Upgraded to Android Studio 3.0: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :appLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730703/upgraded-to-android-studio-3-0-unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-com)

  [Android studio with build tools gradle 3.1.3 unable to download the library dependencies required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102643/android-studio-with-build-tools-gradle-3-1-3-unable-to-download-the-library-depe)

Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance.