# Ionic Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForRelease'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I get this error when I try to build Android on my laptop and in Ionic's Pro dashboard.

```
[04:27:55]: ▸ FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[04:27:55]: ▸ * What went wrong:
[04:27:55]: ▸ Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForRelease'.
[04:27:55]: ▸ > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/43.jar --output /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/45.jar --input /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/49.jar --output /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/51.jar --input /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/37.jar --output /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/39.jar --input /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/3.jar --output /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/5.jar --input /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/28.jar --output /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/30.jar --input /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/47.jar --output /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/49.jar --input /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/19.jar --output /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/21.jar --input /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/44.jar --output /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/release/46.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/CordovaLib/build/intermediates/intermediate-jars/release/classes.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/classes/release --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/0.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/1.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/2.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/3.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/4.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/5.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/6.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/7.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/8.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/9.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/10.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/11.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/12.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/13.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/14.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/15.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/16.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/17.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/18.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/19.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/20.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/21.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/22.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/23.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/24.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/25.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/26.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/27.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/28.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/29.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/30.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/31.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/32.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/33.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/34.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/35.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/36.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/37.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/38.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/39.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/40.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/41.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/42.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/43.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/44.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/45.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/46.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/47.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/48.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/49.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/50.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/51.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/52.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/53.jar --classpath_entry /builds/user/anonymous-social/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/release/54.jar --bootclasspath_entry /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar --bootclasspath_entry /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-27/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 19 --nodesugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}
```

For the entire build details I made a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/QmJ6Tee3

I noticed that if I go into `Platforms > android > project.properties` my details are:

```
target=android-27
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release/bemochi-cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-firebase/bemochi-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.gms:google-services:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:+
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:+
cordova.system.library.9=com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3
cordova.system.library.10=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.+
cordova.system.library.11=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
cordova.system.library.12=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+
cordova.gradle.include.3=me.tonny.cordova.plugins.multidex/bemochi-build.gradle
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm not sure if this helps, but my `build.gradle` has this section:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="27.0.1" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}
```

I also read that when you have this problem you can use 2 plugins to fix it, but they're clearly not working for me (config.xml):

```
<plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="1.4.7">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="15.+" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release" spec="^2.0.0">
    <variable name="FIREBASE_VERSION" value="15.+" />
</plugin>
```

My guess is there is an issue with Firebase and Google services versions but I'm not entirely sure... I've tried multiple versions and I can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas?

Comment: your `build.gradle` looks not correct, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072319/android-studio-3-1-3-gradle-sync-error-could-not-download-gradle-core-jar/51151050#51151050

Comment: @shizhen what's wrong with it? the order of maven and jcenter?

Comment: Yes, it may not be related to your problem in question, but just spot this when reading your post.

Comment: Have you tried changing the targeted android SDK version to 26 ?

Comment: @DelwynPinto 26? I tried it and it still didn't work

Comment: @JaneDoe are you using phonegap-push-plugin ? long back, I had faced the same issue, because of that plugin, conflicting with some values in build.gradle.

Comment: @Vasanth no, no `phonegap-push-plugin` :( here's a full list of my dependencies https://pastebin.com/28JymNHb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem. There was a conflict with my `cordova-plugin-firebase` and `cordova-plugin-google-analytics` so what I ended up having to do was downgrade `cordova-plugin-google-analytics` to version `1.8.3` which ended up working for me.

Simple fix in the end but absolutely 0 indication from the error log that this might be the problem. Very frustrating.

Comment: I had a very similar issue after adding `cordova-plugin-firebase` and removing `cordova-plugin-google-analytics`. If the `cordova-plugin-google-analytics` directory was still cached under my `plugins` directory I still had the issue I.e. I not only had to remove `cordova-plugin-google-analytics` but also manually delete the folder from the plugins directory (at project top level).

Answer (score 2):

**What you have to do**:

1. Delete the **Platform** folder from your project.
2. Open your **ionic project** with **android
   studio**

Now run the following commands in an android studio:

***ionic Cordova build*** then it asks for android and ios then type **Android**

**Feel free to comment for more help** :)

Comment: You can also delete you node-module folder and then run ionic serve and yes to install node module again ... sometimes cause be the node version confliction. And don't afraid, be patience. :)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced to a problem like this.
My problem was with `cordova-plugin-firebase`.
Follow these steps.

**1. Remove Android platform.**

`ionic cordova platform rm android`

**2. Remove `cordova-plugin-firebase` plugin.**

`ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase`

**3. Add `cordova-plugin-firebase` plugin again with version 1.0.0.**

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase@1.0.0`

**4. Add Android platform again.**

`ionic cordova platform add android`

**5. Build Ionic app to Android**

`ionic cordova build android`

Feel free to comment any issue that you faced.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work for me. I got the same problem

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2674#issuecomment-327306830  before try it remove `<plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="1.4.7">
    <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="15.+" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release" spec="^2.0.0">
    <variable name="FIREBASE_VERSION" value="15.+" />
</plugin>` from your config.xml file