# Android Studio 3.2.1: Unfixable Gradle Error

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to create a messaging feature for my application. However, I no longer have to create this feature and I don't know what code I need to delete so that these errors will no longer occur:

> Gradle sync failed: Cannot resolve external dependency
>   com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0 because no repositories are
>   defined. Required by: project : Consult IDE log for more details (Help
>   | Show Log) (504 ms)

Here's my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.SPELFIT.profile"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}

dependencies {
    implementation ('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.11.0@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
}


repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: where is the error? we have to guess the error?

Comment: @ZaidMirza Gradle sync failed: Cannot resolve external dependency com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0 because no repositories are defined.
    Required by:
    project :
    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (504 ms)

Answer (score 3):

Add `google()` as the **first** repo for **all** your

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // must be the first one!!!!
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // must be the first one!!!!
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839

Answer (score 0):

add `google` repo.

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
```

Comment: I did that. But now in Android studio, it says updating indices and it just keeps buffering.

Comment: it will take time... it will download some of them.

Comment: I am still getting the same error saying that the repositories are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot resolve external dependency
>   com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0

Find project root `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {

   repositories {             // add this tag, if you don't have with repo
      google()
      jcenter()
   }

   dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
   }
}
```

Hopefully you've proper net connection and make sure you've not checked **Offline work** in Global Gradle settings.