# Android Studio installation troubleshooting

Tags: java, android

I have installed Android Studio on my Mac. After installing, I simply created an application with an empty `Activity`. No coding, nothing I implemented, just checking my Android Studio. Tried to run that and am getting these errors:

```
Error: Read timed out 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApplication'.
```

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.3.1/builder-3.3.1.jar'.
>   *Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more logout. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   -Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>   BUILD FAILED in 57s
>   Read timed out

I have tried installing all the Gradles, 3.3.1, 4010.0, 3.5.1.
I have changed the Gradle version in `build.gradle` and installed all Gradle versions and checked all. Still, it's not working. I am getting the same error.
Earlier, I got the "unable to find the trusted certificate to requested target" but solved that by adding the certificate to the keystore.
Now I am unable to understand why this error is so difficult to fix.
It's just an empty `Activity` application with no implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure that your have your `google()` properly configured in your `repositories{}`, i.e.

```
repositories {
    google() // make this repo as the first one if Android Gradle Plugin is upgraded from 2.x to 3.x. 
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839 for more detailes.

Secondly, **Check your Proxy for gradle**

Under your Android project root directory, find `gradle.properties` file and add below settings:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=my-example-proxy.com
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=my-example-proxy.com
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
# Add all your hosts that should be bypassed by your proxy server.
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

Note that this proxy setting will apply to your gradle build commands as well.